# Python multiprocessing worker queue for Tensorflow

Tags: python

Tensorflow can run for a long training session and that can crash a server between refreshes of a page.

I'm hoping I can use the following from a previous answer to fix this:

I have a python function that has to run 12 times in total. I have this set up currently to use Pool from the multiprocessing library to run up to all of them in parallel. Typically I run 6 at a time because the function is CPU intensive and running 12 in parallel often causes the program to crash. When we do 6 at a time, the second set of 6 will not begin until all of the first 6 processes are finished. Ideally, we would like another one (e.g. the 7th) to kick off as soon as one from the initial batch of 6 is finished- So that 6 are running at once while there are more to start. Right now the code looks like this (it would be called twice, passing the first 6 elements in one list and then the second 6 in another:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def start_pool(project_list):

    pool = Pool(processes=6)
    pool.map(run_assignments_parallel,project_list)
```

So i have been trying to implement a worker/queue solution and have run into some issues. I have a worker function that looks like this:

```
def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    try:
        for proj in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
            print proj
            run_assignments_parallel(proj)
            done_queue.put('finished ' + proj )
    except Exception, e:        
        done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, proj,        e.message))
    return True
```

And the code to call the worker function is as follows:

```
workers = 6
work_queue = Queue()
done_queue = Queue()  
processes = []
for project in project_list:
    print project
    work_queue.put(project)
for w in xrange(workers):        
    p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)
    work_queue.put('STOP')
for p in processes:
     p.join()    
     done_queue.put('STOP')
for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):        
    print status
```

`project_list` is just a list of paths for the 12 projects that need to be run in the function `run_assignments_parallel`.

The way this is written now, the function is getting called more than once for the same process (project) and I cant really tell what is going on. This code is based on an example i found and I am pretty sure the looping structure is messed up. Any help would be great and I aplogize for my ignorance on the matter. Thanks!

---

This seems to run paths, like filenames with python inside, I'm hoping to place this in my views path of my django server and get it to run through the tensorflow training sessions

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal running example made from your snippets. I converted your code to Python 3 as Python 2 is deprecated and no new code should be written with this version.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing.process import current_process
from queue import Queue


def worker(work_queue, done_queue):
    proj=None
    try:
        for proj in iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP'):
            print(current_process().name, "#", proj)
            done_queue.put('finished ' + proj )
    except Exception as e:
        done_queue.put("%s failed on %s with: %s" % (current_process().name, proj, e.args))
    print(current_process().name, "#", "Quit")
    return True

def main():
    workers = 6
    work_queue = Queue()
    done_queue = Queue()
    processes = []
    project_list = list("ab")
    for project in project_list:
        work_queue.put(project)
    for w in range(workers):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(work_queue, done_queue))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        work_queue.put('STOP')
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
        done_queue.put('STOP')
    for status in iter(done_queue.get, 'STOP'):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Process-1 # a
Process-1 # b
Process-2 # a
Process-2 # b
Process-2 # Quit
Process-3 # a
Process-3 # b
Process-3 # Quit
Process-4 # a
Process-4 # b
Process-4 # Quit
Process-5 # a
Process-5 # b
Process-5 # Quit
Process-6 # a
Process-6 # b
Process-6 # Quit
```

As you can see, each project is handled in each worker.
However the main processe hangs while joining processes because the `Process-1` never terminates...
I think this is due to the `iter(work_queue.get, 'STOP')` call, and I don't understand what you try to achieve there.

The way you use queues seems strange to me.
I advise you to read deeper the [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) module documentation, and in particular the [`task_done`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done) method, that must go in pair with `get`.

Finally, why did you not stick to the `Pool` solution that, I think, is the best suited to your problem.
Pool will automatically handle waiting queue and will make sure that as much as possible (6) workers are running concurrently.